# How to programmaticaly check if RMI class loader is enabled

Tags: java, security, rmi

I am currently performing a review on tons of hosts exposing RMI registries and servers.
I used ton run nmap and metasploit to detect if the class loader was enabled on them, but I am currently willing to understand better than sending serialized object without knowledge.
Basically, with Java, how may I check if the remote class loader is enabled ? Do I have a way to retrieve the remote codebase ?
Or should everything be done blindy : try to perform remote class loading a catch underlying exceptions ?

Thank you by advance, hope I am clear :)

Comment: If your RMI application relies on the codebase feature and it isn't enabled, it won't run. Hard to see why you need a runtime test for that, but just examine the system property `java.rmi.server.codebase` at the exporting JVM. If set, it is in use. You can't detect it from the other end.

Comment: @EJP I always have to look stuff up with RMI. I believe  `java.rmi.server.codebase` contains the annotation data sent to the other end in the serialised stream. `java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly` is the magic system property that when set to `false` enables remote class loading (I think the default is now `true`; it used to be `false`).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline So [look it up](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html). If `java.rmi.server.codebase` is set, the classes are annotated. If it isn't, they aren't. `java.rmi.server.useCodeBaseOnly` *prevents* the local system from using any *other* codebase than the one defined in its own `java.rmi.server.codebase`, but it doesn't *enable* it. Only the presence of the annotation in the classes (and a local `SecurityManager`) does that.

Comment: @EJP My interpretation of the question is "How do I detect if a process will load remote classes?". (The attacker sends the annotation to the victim. The victim then loads a malicious class from anywhere it is told.) (The answer for a pentest is presumably that sucking and seeing is the only way.)